# generate value in overrided attribute

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have class for ID

```
@org.hibernate.annotations.AccessType("property")
public class ObjectID implements java.io.Serializable
{   
private long value;  

    long getValue()
    {
       return value;
    }

    void setValue(Long id)
    {
       value = id != null ? id : 0L;
    }
  // equals, hash, contructor  
}
```

And have mapped class (Patient) that used this ID-class. I want generate long value in ObjectID class. help me.
I tried

```
public class Patient implements Serializable 
{
   @javax.persistence.Id
   @javax.persistence.Column(name = "aa_id")
   @org.hibernate.annotations.Formula("case when aa_id is null then patient_seq.nextval else aa_id end")
   @javax.persistence.AttributeOverride(name = "value", column = @Column(name = "aa_id"))
   private ObjectID id;
}
```

and

```
public class Patient implements Serializable 
{
   @javax.persistence.Id
   @javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator(name = "PatientSequenceGenerator",
                       sequenceName = "patient_seq")
   @javax.persistence.GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
                    generator = "PatientSequenceGenerator")
   @javax.persistence.AttributeOverride(name = "value", column = @Column(name = "aa_id"))
   private ObjectID id;
}
```

But there are not helpful

One of resolves of this situation is to write custom userType for ObjectID and write custom ID-generator.

Comment: What's the point of embedding the long ID into ObjectID? Why not use Long as ID directly?

Comment: You can't use GeneratedValue on a non-numeric/String field except using imnplementation-specifics (i.e to be avoided, and not likely to work anyway).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

compositeIds are normally assigned by the program and i do not know if there is even a possibility to set it (or parts of it) through a databasesequence out of the box.

first you could try to set it this way to see if it works:

```
public class Patient implements Serializable 
{
   @Id
   @SequenceGenerator(name = "PatientSequenceGenerator", sequenceName = "lab_patient_seq")
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "PatientSequenceGenerator")
   private Long id;
}
```

Comment: It works well, I tried this later. Now I am changing Long -> ObjectID

Comment: then you probably need to implement a UserType to get it to work